# Net Electric Field of Multiple Charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

> Question: Four charges, each of magnitude +Q are placed at the corners of a square of side a. Obtain an expression for the electric potential at the centre of the square and at the mid point of one side. What is the direction of the electric field at the centre of the square and at the mid-point of the side.

Just some guidance with breaking down the components and starting to resolve the problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want an answer based off of $E=\frac{F}{q}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uggh. I hate this kind of problem because of all the different components you have to deal with. But I'll just start it, like you asked.

The electric field of a charge is defined as $E=\frac{F}{q}$. Now we know that $F=k\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$, so $E=k\frac{q_1}{r^2}$. A test chargeanywhere in this space has to contend with four electric fields: $E_1$,$E_2$,$E_3$, and $E_4$.

For a given field, first find the distance from a point to the charge. Use the Pythagorean theorem:

$$r^2=x^2+y^2$$

Plug that in and you have
$$E_1=k\frac{q_1}{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$$
where $x_2$ and $y_2$ are the coordinates of the test charge.

Now we break this field up into its x- and y- components.
$$E_1^2=E_{x1}^2+E_{y1}^2$$

Do this for all four charges. Then add up all the x- and y- components:
$$\sum E_x=E_{x1}+E_{x2}+E_{x3}+E_{x4}$$
and
$$\sum E_y=E_{y1}+E_{y2}+E_{y3}+E_{y4}$$
Finally, use the Pythagorean theorem one last time:
$$\left (\sum E \right)^2=\left (\sum E_x \right)^2+\left (\sum E_y \right)^2$$
and so
$$\sum E=\sqrt{\left (\sum E_x \right)^2+\left (\sum E_y \right)^2}$$